# can't connect to Parse with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

Im new on Parse.. I'm trying to connect to parse with Xcode, I'm follow the guide and this steps "Test the SDK" doesn't work for me. When om follow the guide and write exactly what they say on the website and run the app there an window pop up "build failed" and Xcode say " "PFObject" does not have a member named "SaveinBackground".

```
var testObject: PFObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
    testObject["Foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.SaveinBackground()
```

How can i fix this ?

help me plz..

have a nice day!

Comment: Did you initialize your ParseFramework in the delegate?

Comment: That code is Swift, not Objective-C.  The method is probably named saveInBackground (lowercase "s", uppercase "I").  The languages are case-sensitive.

Comment: ashraf, yes i have initialize that..

Comment: anna: but how do i write ? doesn't work with swift ? I'm programming in swift.

Comment: `saveInBackground` not `SaveinBackground`

Comment: doesn't work. i have test all. upper and low case. error and "PFObject" does not have a member named "saveInBackground".

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow this guide: http://codewithchris.com/using-parse-swift-xcode-6/? This is for Swift. Maybe that could help.